# Can an NPC Duergar end a size change early?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, npc

Let's say a regular NPC Duergar is Large, and wants to hide behind something Smallish, or a Mind Master is currently Tiny and he knows he'll be making Athletics checks in less than a minute. Their stat blocks don't say that there's any specific way to end these effects before the end of the duration, but is there a general rule somewhere else that says they can just turn off the size shift?

Comment: Hey Niall, I've closed this as a duplicate for now, I think that question is presenting the same problem - an effect that doesn't have any end condition besides its duration. I'm still looking for other duplicates, I suspect we've had had this question before more than once.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, the Wand of Wonder case is similar enough for me. That's the way I ruled it in my game anyway

Comment: Isn't the Duergar concentrating on this effect?  It looks like the Wand is doing the "concentrating" in the linked question.   Nevermind...   I looked at the related question and that answered that.

Comment: The Duergar isn't concentrating, because it says that they are for their Invisibility ability but not for this one.